# Update StringVar in tkinter entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Could someone please tell me the accepted way in python 3 to update the stringvar in a tinker entry. In the code below I would like text in the entry to change from "default text" to "new text" once the button is pressed. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def get_var():
    new_text = "new text"
    print(new_text)

window = Tk()
window.title("My Program")

v = StringVar(window, value='default text')
case_name_lbl = Label(window, text="Case Name:").pack(padx=10, pady=10, 
side=LEFT)
case_name_entry = Entry(window, textvariable=v)
case_name_entry.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)

btn = Button(window, text='File', width=10, command=get_var)
btn.pack(in_=window, padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

set the textvariable:

```
def get_var():
    new_text = "new text"
    v.set(new_text)
    print(new_text)
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
def get_var():
    case_name_entry.delete(0, END)
    new_text = "new text"
    print(new_text)
    case_name_entry.insert(0, new_text)
```

it will clear the entry and insert the text in it and don't import `tkinter` with wildcard `*` so the is no need to import like that since you done `import tkinter as tk`.Also where you position you `Stringvar` will be very difficult if along the line you want to debug your.The following is well structure of your code.

**FULL CODE**

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_var():
    case_name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    new_text = "new text"
    print(new_text)
    case_name_entry.insert(0, new_text)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My Program")


case_name_lbl = tk.Label(window, text="Case Name:")
case_name_lbl.pack(padx=10, pady=10,side=tk.LEFT)

v = tk.StringVar(window, value='default text')
case_name_entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=v)
case_name_entry.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)

btn = tk.Button(window, text='File', width=10, command=get_var)
btn.pack(in_=window, padx=10, pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```